# ASP.NET MVC ReturnUrl confusion when application is hosted as a virtual directory under a site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, forms-authentication, returnurl

I was hoping that somebody could shed some light on how to get around a ReturnUrl issue that I am having. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application that I had running under the default website and everything looked fine...the ReturnUrl is pointing to a Search action on a Basic controller:

```
http://localhost/Login/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fBasic%2fSearch
```

If I move this application over to another machine and deploy it in a virtual directory, I get a different ReturnUrl:

```
http://localhost2/virtualdirectory/Login/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fvirtualdirectory%2fBasic%2fSearch
```

Now the "virtualdirectory" is showing in the ReturnUrl and of course it doesn't route properly.

In my web.config, I have configured the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Any help, or suggestions, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically when it redirects it redirects to: http://localhost2/virtualdirectory/BasicSearch That looks like it should work? What is the redirection url after login?

Comment: @Victor The url is: localhost2/virtualdirectory/virtualdirectory/Basic/Search  We are trying to get localhost2/virtualdirectory/Basic/Search

Comment: @Rob No, we didn't figure this out. Instead, we started using virtual sites and that solved the address problems that we were having. Sorry that it's not a solution-type answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're doing the redirect. If you're redirecting like this, it should work:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   //... omitted some preliminary validation ...
   return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

We're using this setup and it works with virtual directories.